# Errors in a factory

Tags: probability

I am trying to learn probability for my next year at University.

I am really struggling with this exercise and have no idea how to start solving it.

In a warehouse there are 100 products, 60 of them are from the first factory, while the other 40 are from the second factory. 3% of the products of the first factory have errors, and 6% of the second factory. what is the probability that the product randomly taken from the warehouse has errors?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts, and to explain the connection you see with "improper integrals".

Comment: @lulu my fault, meant to put it into the probability section, Thank you

Comment: There is a slight issue here with wording and integers, but how many products from the first factory do you expect to have errors? how many from the second factory? how many in total? what proportion in total?

Comment: @Henry "*3% of the products of the first factory have errors*"  I interpret that to mean that the factory produces *many* such items, that $3\%$ of the "*many*" are defective, and some random selection of the items made are sent to our warehouse in question.  The answer to your questions should be obvious and already taken care of in the problem statement.

Comment: @JMoravitz The answer to my last question "what proportion in total do you expect to have errors?" is indeed obvious but is not in the problem statement - it is the answer to the original question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a textbook example of the multiplication principle of probability.  Let $A$ be the event the item comes from the first factory which makes $A^c$ the event it comes from the second factory.  The problem statement tells us what $\Pr(A)$ is from the sentence:

> "*60 of them are from the first factory while the other 40 are from the second factory.*"

Let $E$ be the event the item has an error.  We are told in the problem statement $\Pr(E\mid A)$ and $\Pr(E\mid A^c)$ from the sentences:

> "*3% of the products of the first factory have errors, and 6% of the second factory*"

That is to say, the information given to us is:

> $\Pr(A)=0.6,~\Pr(A^c)=0.4,~\Pr(E\mid A)=0.03,~\Pr(E\mid A^c)=0.06$

We are tasked with finding $\Pr(E)$.  From multiplication principle, we know that $$\Pr(E)=\Pr(E\cap (A\cup A^c))=\Pr(E\cap A)+\Pr(E\cap A^c)$$

$$=\Pr(A)\Pr(E\mid A)+\Pr(A^c)\Pr(E\mid A^c)$$

We have all of the necessary information and so we can complete the problem

> $$0.6\cdot 0.03+0.4\cdot 0.06$$

Comment: Thank you for this answer, I think I need to use more time to understand probability since this is quite complicated for me. So, in the end, we see that the probability is 4.2%?

Comment: Visualize it as a [tree diagram](https://www.mathsisfun.com/data/probability-tree-diagrams.html).  The first branching point was whether the item came from the first factory vs the second.  The next branching points for each were whether they had errors or not.

Answer (score 1):

If it  seems very complicated to you, just think of it as the weighted average of the probability of a random piece from the warehouse being defective, which is

$0.6\cdot 0.03+0.4\cdot 0.06$

This is the law of total probability which you can look up [here](https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter1/1_4_2_total_probability.php)

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Glad to be of help ! $\;$ :)